# Magnolia - Instantiate fail with a module class

Tags: java, module, command, scheduler, magnolia

When I need starting a command with scheduler I have the next error in console:
[image]
[image]

I'm going to line 66 that log said me and i can see this:
[image]

This class WsProuser has a Null pointer Exception when i try get the instance. This class is a default class of module where i saved some configurations. This is a part of META-INF xml where i reference this class:
[image]

And this is the implementation of this class:

[image]
[image]

For finish, this is the config where i save the values that i need in the command:
[image]

¿Why i have this NullPointer Exception when magnolia should instanciate automating this class?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any information about your package structure, but I think the `<class />` element from module descriptor should be:

```
<class>es.vass.magnolia.module.wsprouser.WsProuser</class>
```

It looks like you are repeating the class name.

**Update:** After reading the log, I saw that the NPE is thrown when the module `ui-admincentral` is started. At that time, your custom module `ws-prouser-prosegur-intra-module` is not started yet, so the static instance is still `null`. In order to work this way you should add a dependency to your module in `ui-admincentral`, but given that this is a magnolia module, you can't do that. What I would recommend is to inject a `Provider<WsProuser>` in your CommandGenerator and use that instead of `WsProuser.getInstance()`. Then use this provider where you actually need it, not in constructor.

Comment: My package is "es.vass.magnolia.module.wsprouser.WsProuser", for this reason that is not the fail.